# Формы с одинаковым id на странице

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

Добрый день,
есть задача выводить сообщения(коменты) на страницу. Вывожу их циклом:

```html
<c:forEach items="${commentsList}" var="comment1st">
<c:if test="${comment1st.primaryCommentID == null}">
        <fmt:formatDate value="${comment1st.getUpdated()}" pattern="d-MM-yyyy, HH:mm:ss"/><br>
        ${comment1st.text}

        <!---------------Hiding button and field for answering----------------------->
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="viewdiv('mydiv');">Reply</a>
    <div id="mydiv" style="display:none;">
        <form:form id="replycomment1" method="POST" modelAttribute="comment" action="/replycomment/${deal.id}/${comment1st.id}/${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}/${comment1st.author.username}/">
          <textarea name="text" rows="5" path="text" class="form" cols="50" placeholder='Add a comment...${text}' class="text"></textarea><br>
          <button type="submit" id="replycomment1" style="float: left">
            <spring:message text="Submit"/>
          </button><br>
          <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

также есть скрипт для сворачивания формы с полем ввода ответа

```js
function viewdiv(id){
            var el=document.getElementById(id);
            if(el.style.display=="block"){
                el.style.display="none";
            } else {
                el.style.display="block";
            }
        }
```

при каждой итерации цикла по идее должна быть свернутая форма с полем для ввода ответа для каждого выведенного комента, но поскольку там стоит id="mydiv" и при каждой итерации id не меняется, то форма и скрипт работаю только для первого вызова.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Заменить айди на класс?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как это корректно сделать?

Comment: Согласно [документации](https://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.10), использовать можно только [уникальные идентификаторы](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Comment: Mr. Brightside, это я уже знаю, но как выйти из этой ситуации?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский Например, в **onclick="viewdiv('mydiv' + ID);"** добавлять id записи, в **<div id="mydiv" + ID** добавлять тот же айдишник (у вас же циклом выводится). Замена id на класс, как мне кажется, не поможет, потому что нужно уникально определять, под каким комментарием разворачивать поле для ввода нового комментария (комментировать комментарий) - это своего рода relation. Кстати, как вы храните цепочки комментариев?

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский хотя нет, вы можете переместить mydiv и в класс, и при клике в Reply просто находить sibling с этим классом и скрывать/показывать его. Кстати, рекомендую переименовать viewdiv в toggleDiv или toggleCommentBlock.

Comment: Mr. Brightside, подскажите пожалуйста как корректно переместить   mydiv в класс? просто заменить id на class? только недавно начал разбираться с этими технологиями, много чего пока не понимаю.

Comment: Mr. Brightside, по поводу хранения цепочки комментариев. Каждый коммент- это java объект, который содержит информацию о родительском комменте.(те комменты у которых родительский = null и есть сами родительские, остальные дочерние-то есть ответы) Вывожу отсортированные  по времени родительские и вложенным циклом для каждого выводу отсортированные дочерние. Надеюсь не сильно запутанно написал

Comment: @ЛеонидДубравский у элементов на странице есть атрибут class. Да, вам нужно заменить id на class: <div class="myDiv">. Если на элемент потребуется навесить стили через класс, то получится <div class="styleClass myDiv">. Далее вам необходимо после клика на <a> найти [sibling](https://plainjs.com/javascript/traversing/get-siblings-of-an-element-40/). Только в условие поиска необходимо добавить проверку на наличие ключевого класса myDiv.

Comment: Mr. Brightside, осталось понять, как работает sibling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил медодом подстановки id сушности (которую вывожу) в id формы. Может конечно коряво, но работает.

```html
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#${comment1st.getId()}">Reply</a>
            <div id=${comment1st.getId()} class="collapse">
                <form:form id="replycomment1" method="POST" modelAttribute="comment" action="/replycomment/${deal.id}/${comment1st.id}/${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}/${comment1st.author.username}/">
                    <textarea name="text" rows="5" path="text" class="form" cols="50" placeholder='Add a comment...${text}' class="text"></textarea><br>
                    <br>
                    <button type="submit" id="replycomment1" style="float: left">
                        <spring:message text="Submit"/>
                    </button><br>
                    <input type="hidden"  name="${_csrf.parameterName}"   value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                </form:form><br>
            </div>
```